# Display a blank row between every unique row?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a simple query like:

```
SELECT employee, ITEM_TYPE, COUNT(ITEM_TYPE)
FROM   hr_database
```

So the output may  look like

```
 BOB  MUGS  4 
 BOB  PENCILS 10 
 CAT  MUGS  2 
 CAT  PAPERCLIPS  7 
 SAL  MUGS  11
```

But for readability, I want to put a blank row between each user in the output(i.e for readability), like this :

```
 BOB  MUGS  4 
 BOB  PENCILS 10 

 CAT  MUGS  2 
 CAT  PAPERCLIPS  7 

 SAL  MUGS  11
```

Is there a way to do this in Oracle SQL ?  So far, [I found this link but it doesn't match what I need](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1041758) . I'm thinking to use a WITH in the query?

Comment: I am not sure this is possible with straight SQL, I would imagine you would have to do some kind of logic with whatever you are using to display the information with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in the database, but this type of processing should really be done at the application layer.

But, it is kind of an amusing trick to figure out how to do it in the database, and that is your specific question:

```
WITH e AS (
      SELECT employee, ITEM_TYPE, COUNT(ITEM_TYPE) as cnt
      FROM hr_database
      GROUP BY employee, ITEM_TYPE
     )
SELECT (case when cnt is not null then employee end) as employee,
       item_type, cnt
FROM (select employee, item_type, cnt, 1 as x from e union all
      select distinct employee, NULL, NULL, 2 as x from e
     ) e
ORDER BY e.employee, x;
```

I emphasize, though, that this is really for amusement and perhaps for understanding better how SQL works.  In the real world, you do this type of work at the application layer.

A summary of how this works.  The `union all` brings in one additional row for each employee.  The `x` is a priority for sorting -- because you have to sort the result set to get the proper ordering.  The `case` statement is needed to prevent the `employee` from being in the first column.  `cnt` should never be `NULL` for the valid rows.

Comment: Thanks very much ! that is pretty tricky SQL !! I can see what you mean by "the real world, you do this type of work at the application layer"

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this with normal union & distinct

```
select emp,item_type,cnt from 
(select distinct ' ' as emp,' ' as item_type ,' ' as cnt, employee
from hr_database
union
select employee as emp,item_type ,to_char(count(item_type)) as cnt, employee
from hr_database
group by employee,item_type)a
order by a.employee
```